# Javascript: Trying to load highcharts without freezing the browser

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, highcharts

I need to load n graphs, but instead of waiting 1 min with the browser frozen, I would like that once the first graph is created / rendered, it appears on the screen before moving to the next one.

I am using a "strategy" that works in another part of my code, why is not working here?

The code:

```
var i = -1;
var total = 10;
function moveToTheNext() {
    saySomething()
    .then(function() {return $timeout(function(){},1000);})
    .then(nextChart());
    }

function saySomething() {
    console.log('hey')
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    deferred.resolve();
    return deferred.promise;
    }

function nextChart() {
    i++;
    if (i <= total) {
        // some stuff
        chart[i] = new Highcharts.Chart({
            //....
        },moveToTheNext());
        }
    }
```

UPDATE
The error was in the execution of the nextChart function

```
function moveToTheNext() {
    saySomething()
    .then(function() {return $timeout(function(){},1000);})
    .then(function() {nextChart();});
    }
```

Now it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved, see the updated code in the question